# 'SET' opertor in Redshift SQL

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am looking for operation that can be performed as 'SET' in Redshift SQL

I want to perform a similar operation in Redshift SQL. I know MySQL supports but not sure about Redshift SQL.

```
SET @StartDate = '2023-01-01';

SELECT *
FROM Payments
WHERE PurchaseDate >= @StartDate;
```

I didn't get any documentation in Redshift Developer Guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redshift doesn't have SQL level variables so this isn't going to work this way.

What are you trying to achieve by having variable substitution?  There are a number of possible objectives and how to achieve your ends will depend on exactly what objective you are targeting.  You can perform dynamic SQL with stored procedures OR you can enable SQL templating (outside of Redshift) with tools like jinja2.